# How to make 20 LED's light up one at a time and remain on, and then power off one at a time?

Tags: switches

I’m looking to see if there is a circuit I can build that would light up a row of about 20 LED’s one at a time after pressing a button, and keep those LED constantly on once there were activated. Finally, when pressing a button again, they all power off one at a time in the same order?

Comment: People don't generally develop circuits with such a specific purpose. Normally you'd use a LED driver and a microcontroller (an Arduino would probably be easiest to start with) and program that behaviour into it.

Comment: Questions asking for a circuit are closed.

Comment: A SIPO shift register will do by shifting `1`s in, if clocked properly..

Comment: I believe this is called a 'Johnson Counter' or 'Ring Counter'.

Comment: In What order do you want them to power off - First on first off, or last on first off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at a chip family called "shift registers".

For example, a TPIC6595 will drive up 8 LEDs. You simply cascade multiple shift registers to drive more LEDs.

Have a look at that chip, then modify your question with what you have learned.

We will help you get to where you want to be but you have to do the work yourself.

Comment: Thanks, "shift registers" put me on the right path! A few 74HC595 combined with a programmable ATMEGA328P should do what I need.

Comment: Be aware that a 74HC595 is only rated for 6 mA per output. If you want to drive your LEDs harder than that, you can usually get away with it, but you are in territory where the manufacturer doesn't guarantee the chip to work well. The TPIC6595 costs a bit more, but it will handle LOTS more current.